# css для правильного расположение контента

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox

[image: макет]

Нужно сделать как на макете.
Вот как я сделал в html.

```
<section id="about">
        <div class="conteiner">
            <div class="title">
                <h2>
                    About Us
                </h2>
                <p>
                    Proin iaculis purus consequat sem cure.
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="about clearfix">
                <div class="about_item">
                    <img  src="img/about1.jpg" alt="about">
                    <div class="about_item_text">
                        <h3>
                            JULY 2010 <br>
                            Our Humble Beginnings

                        </h3>
                        <p>Proin iaculis purus consequat sem cure
                            digni ssim. Donec porttitora entum suscipit
                            aenean rhoncus posuere odio in tincidunt. Proin
                            iaculis purus consequat sem cure digni
                            ssim. Donec porttitora entum suscipit.
                        </p>
                    </div>
 <! -- ещё 3 таких-же блока --> 
        </div>
</section>
```

В css смог выровнять изображения, но как расположить текст не пойму.

```
.about_item > img { 
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что использовать?

Comment: Вам надо задачу решить на чистом css? Если нет тогда используйте bootstrap

Comment: @JuniorCoder, а Бутстрап - это не чистый css? :))

Comment: Вы правы чистый, имел виду используя фреймворк или нет)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так?

```css
.title h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.title p {
  text-align: center;
  color: gray;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.about_item {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 50px 0;
}
.about_item img {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.item_left,
.item_right {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
}
.item_left {
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
}
.item_right {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
.item_left p,
.item_left h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 70px 0 0;
}
.item_right p,
.item_right h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 70px;
}
```

```html
<section id="about">
  <div class="conteiner">
    <div class="title">
      <h2>
        About Us
      </h2>
      <p>
        Proin iaculis purus consequat sem cure.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="about clearfix">
      <div class="about_item">
        <img src="https://www.pinclipart.com/picdir/big/101-1018330_download-this-wheel-or-find-your-own-clipart.png" alt="about">
        <div class="about_item_text item_left">
          <h3>JULY 2010 <br> Our Humble Beginnings</h3>
          <p>Proin iaculis purus consequat sem cure digni ssim. Donec porttitora entum suscipit aenean rhoncus posuere odio in tincidunt. Proin iaculis purus consequat sem cure digni ssim. Donec porttitora entum suscipit.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="about_item">
        <img src="https://www.pinclipart.com/picdir/big/101-1018330_download-this-wheel-or-find-your-own-clipart.png" alt="about">
        <div class="about_item_text item_right">
          <h3>JULY 2010 <br> Our Humble Beginnings</h3>
          <p>Proin iaculis purus consequat sem cure digni ssim. Donec porttitora entum suscipit aenean rhoncus posuere odio in tincidunt. Proin iaculis purus consequat sem cure digni ssim. Donec porttitora entum suscipit.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="about_item">
        <img src="https://www.pinclipart.com/picdir/big/101-1018330_download-this-wheel-or-find-your-own-clipart.png" alt="about">
        <div class="about_item_text item_left">
          <h3>JULY 2010 <br> Our Humble Beginnings</h3>
          <p>Proin iaculis purus consequat sem cure digni ssim. Donec porttitora entum suscipit aenean rhoncus posuere odio in tincidunt. Proin iaculis purus consequat sem cure digni ssim. Donec porttitora entum suscipit.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="about_item">
        <img src="https://www.pinclipart.com/picdir/big/101-1018330_download-this-wheel-or-find-your-own-clipart.png" alt="about">
        <div class="about_item_text item_right">
          <h3>JULY 2010 <br> Our Humble Beginnings</h3>
          <p>Proin iaculis purus consequat sem cure digni ssim. Donec porttitora entum suscipit aenean rhoncus posuere odio in tincidunt. Proin iaculis purus consequat sem cure digni ssim. Donec porttitora entum suscipit.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
section{
padding: 20px;
}

.primariImg{
background:black;
height:200px;
width:200px;
border-radius:50%;
margin:0 20px;
}

.title h2{
text-align: center;
}

.title p{
text-align: center;
color:grey;
}

.about{
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

.about_item_text{

width:400px;
}
.about_item_text p{
text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<section id="about">
        <div class="conteiner">
            <div class="title">
                <h2>
                    About Us
                </h2>
                <p>
                    Proin iaculis purus consequat sem cure.
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="about">
              <div class="primariImg"></div>
                <div class="about_item">
                    <div class="about_item_text">
                        <h3>
                            JULY 2010 <br>
                            Our Humble Beginnings

                        </h3>
                        <p>Proin iaculis purus consequat sem cure
                            digni ssim. Donec porttitora entum suscipit
                            aenean rhoncus posuere odio in tincidunt. Proin
                            iaculis purus consequat sem cure digni
                            ssim. Donec porttitora entum suscipit.
                        </p>
                    </div>
 <! -- ещё 3 таких-же блока --> 
        </div>
</section>
```